# Swift: Can't make the PhotoEditPreviewController's background transparent when adding it on top of another view

Tags: ios, photoeditorsdk

I'm placing `PhotoEditPreviewController` on top of a custom view, which is initialized by setting a transparent image. There is a `SpriteEditController` in the `PhotoEditPreviewController` used for text editing. In the Hierarchy structure of the views, I can see that there is a `GLKView` which is showing transparent in iPhone 6 and 6s but takes a black background color on iPhone 7, 8 and 10(X). I need that `GLKView` to be transparent I've tried getting this GLView from the views and setting its layer and background color. But nothing seems to work on these devices.

[image: View Hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `PhotoEditPreviewController`'s `delegate` to set the background color. Something like this should do it:

```
photoEditPreviewController.delegate = self
```

and then

```
extension ViewController: PhotoEditPreviewControllerDelegate {
  func photoEditPreviewControllerResetProxyZooming(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) {
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerPreviewEnabled(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerDidChangePhotoEditModel(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) {
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerPreviewScale(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerBackgroundColor(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) -> UIColor {
    // Return the desired background color here.
    return .clear
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerProxyZoomingActive(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) -> Bool {
    return false
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerPreviewInsets(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return .zero
  }

  func photoEditPreviewControllerRenderMode(_ photoEditPreviewController: PhotoEditPreviewController) -> PESDKRenderMode {
    return .all
  }
}
```